# Navigation Key lost after trying to delete

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have code first entity framework.
when I'm trying to delete row from table that have foreign key to other table i get a exception. after handling the exception when I try load my data again the **Navigation Key** of selected item that i try to delete is become **null**

why this happen and how can i fix it.

the delete process is so simple :

```
public class Person
{
     public int ID {get;set;}
     public string Name {get;set;}

     public Something Something {get;set;}
     public ICollection<Profile> Profile {get;set;}
}

try 
{
    var p = en.Person.First(t => t.ID == 14);
    //p.Something here is not null;
    en.Remove(p)
    en.SaveChanges(); // I'm get an exception here
} 
catch { /*error handling */} 
finally 
{
    var p = en.Person.First(t => t.ID == 14);
    //but p.Something here is null;
}
```

but in **en.SaveChange()** i get an exception.

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_person_profile

this is a sample of my class.
that **SomeThing** Property is a Navigation Key.
in first select the **Something** have value.
but in second select inside **finally** block its become null.

after fixing the delete problem now I got the same problem after adding object to database.
and that reload function doesn't help.
any suggestion?

Comment: Can you post your code? Your delete function, and the method that's throwing the error would be helpful!

Comment: Your error is because there's a **required** FK relationship that's not set to cascade on delete (it looks like you have a profile object).  You'll either need to make the relationship optional, delete the profile, or enable cascade on delete.

Comment: also i have exact same problem

Comment: @MarkOreta : here some more update on my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your problem - you're deleting an entity, it's causing an error and you want to recover.  However, in your finally block when you get your entity again from your current context again it's not correct.

The issue is that you're expecting your context to reload from the database, but that's not quite how it works. What you're actually doing is going back to your context, which is a unit of work and retrieving the entity in memory, because the entity your retrieving is flagged for deletion so it's properties are not being loaded. If you want to refresh from the database, you'll need to reload the entity fully using the Entry, using the [DbEntityEntry.Reload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679450%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

Using your code an an example:

```
var p = en.Person.First(t => t.ID == 14);
en.Entry(p).Reload();
```